# Is there a word for "to announce one's arrival"?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

Is there a word for announcing someone's arrival, kind of like a prelude for something or someone important?

Comment: Ironically, the best word, in general, *is* **announce**. Why do you think that a different word would be better?

Comment: Oh I was probably thinking of, how do i explain this...it's like when a king or any royalty arrives there's someone announcing his name and the kingdom he is from in a loud voice. It's the same for announcing arrived guests for a royal ball. So I thought there was a specific verb or noun for it or the person doing it

Comment: The person *doing* the announcing is the herald (which fits the answer below) or master of ceremonies.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think of the verb [**to herald**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/herald_2)? It sounds like this one is exactly the word you're looking for. Here's how the Macmillan English Dictionary defines it:

> (mainly literary) to announce something, or to be a sign that something is going to happen soon

Example:

> The recent discovery of large deposits of gold is **heralding** a new era of prosperity in the region.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the closest thing I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The thesaurus has:

Definition: declare arrival
Synonyms: predict, indicate, signal, harbinger, signify, forecast, herald, forebode, foretell, augur, portend, presage, foreshow, forerun

... All x of which have the problem that "i xed" or "i was xed" not neccessarily means " i announced my arrival" or "my arrival was announced" but can also be construed as "my **existence** was predicted".  So most can be used with arrival but none strongly imply arrival if the announced event is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little informal, but you can "verbify" the (normally, *exclamatory*) usage...

> **cooee** *- used to attract attention, especially at a distance.* [<sub>(oxforddictionaries.com)</sub>](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cooee)

...as in many of the written instances of things like...

> *As he approached, [he cooeed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%20cooeed%22) loudly, but there was no response.*

---

Apart from that, I do not believe there's a single-word (or simple "compound verb" based on ***self-*** prefix or reflexive ***oneself***) English verb with the specific meaning *draw attention to oneself, announce one's presence*. But I'd be happy to be proved wrong!